# classification of 5x5 $\mathbb{Q}$ matrices upto similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, computational-algebra

A'm asking for normal form similar to JNF.
What I'm thinking is to look at representing all degree 5 or less algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, and modify the "jordan" blocks in the classification.

Maybe it'll be easier to answer for 2 or 3 dimensional matrices?

Comment: There's the Rational Canonical Form.